# navigation using <a> </a> tag in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, navigation

I am currently using `<a>` tag to click and navaigate as mentioned in below code.I want to navigate the below code in c# tag in page_prerender event based on id selected.could any one help on this?

```
<li><a href="#" rel="cat1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="cat2">Category 2</a></li>
    <div id="cat1">
    Content goes here
    </div>
    <div id="cat2">
    Content goes here
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand your question. I've read it a few times but still don't know what you're asking. Could you rephrase it perhaps?

Comment: I think questioner wants to display the correct div in the prerender? Perhaps via a url hashtag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like if url doesn't contain '#' then

```
Response.Redirect("www.yoururl.com/Default.aspx#Cat2");
```

is that what you're looking for?

clicking on the `<a>` in html is really the same as just adding `#Cat2` to the end of the URL , the browser knows what to do from there

Comment: it contains # <a href="#" rel="cat2">Category 2</a>

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a url rewriting layer for how you have it.  The `<a>` links are simply going to be a `GET` request with no further information.  And even then you would need the links to be `href="cat1"` or `href="#cat1"`.

The simplest alternative would be using `<asp:linkbutton />` which can have server-side onclick events.

You might also look into AJAX requests, or use javascript to hide and display the sections, if the content is dynamic based on the request AJAX would be required there.